# $H^1_0(\Omega)\cap H^2(\Omega)$ is not dense on $H^1_0(\Omega)\cap H,$ where $H = \{v\in L_2(\Omega),\;\Delta\,v\in L_2{(\Omega)}\}$

Tags: functional-analysis

I came across with the following statement: The space $H^1_0(\Omega)\cap H^2(\Omega)$ is not dense on $H^1_0(\Omega)\cap H,$ where $H = \{v\in L_2(\Omega),\;\Delta\,v\in L_2{(\Omega)}\},$ where $\Omega$ is connected and open polygonal domain of $\mathbb{R}^2.$

Is there any hint how to deal with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn’t specify what norms you are using in those spaces. But if you are taking the sums, then this could be a solution.
Assume that $\Omega$ near the origin is given by $$\{(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta):\,0<r<1,\, 0<\theta<\omega\}$$ and consider the function given near the origin by $$u=r^{\pi/\omega}\sin(\pi\theta/\omega)$$ where we assume that $\pi/\omega$ is not an integer. You can check that $u$  is harmonic, is zero on the two boundary segments but it is not in $H^2$